# Find all fields that may contain part of the searched

Tags: sql, search

I have this code and it works perfectly when I'm searching something specific. How can I change it so it will work even if I know only part of the Order_ID for example. I tried everything and I guess I'm just not doing it the right way.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ANNA\MSSQLSERVER2012;Initial Catalog=Wine house;Integrated Security=True;");
con.Open();

string strSQL1 = "";
if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
{
    if (strSQL1.Length > 0)
    {
        strSQL1 = strSQL1 + " AND ";
    }
    strSQL1 = strSQL1 + "Order_ID=" + textBox1.Text;

}

if (textBox2.Text.Length > 0)
{
    if (strSQL1.Length > 0)
    {
        strSQL1 = strSQL1 + " AND ";
    }
    strSQL1 = strSQL1 + "Client_ID=" + textBox2.Text;
}

if (textBox3.Text.Length > 0)
{
    if (strSQL1.Length > 0)
    {
        strSQL1 = strSQL1 + " AND ";
    }
    strSQL1 = strSQL1 + "Amount_due=" + textBox3.Text;
}

if (textBox4.Text.Length > 0)
{
    if (strSQL1.Length > 0)
    {
        strSQL1 = strSQL1 + " AND ";
    }
    strSQL1 = strSQL1 + "Employee_ID=" + textBox4.Text;
}

if (textBox5.Text.Length > 0)
{
    if (strSQL1.Length > 0)
    {
        strSQL1 = strSQL1 + " AND ";
    }
    strSQL1 = strSQL1 + "DeliveryDate='" + textBox5.Text;
}

if (textBox6.Text.Length > 0)
{
    if (strSQL1.Length > 0)
    {
        strSQL1 = strSQL1 + " AND ";
    }
    strSQL1 = strSQL1 + "Delivered='" + textBox6.Text + "'";
}

if (strSQL1.Length > 0)
{
    strSQL1 = @"SELECT Order_ID, Client_ID, Amount_due, Employee_ID, CONVERT(nvarchar, DeliveryDate, 104) AS DeliveryDate, Delivered FROM Orders WHERE" + strSQL1;
}
else
{
    strSQL1 = @"SELECT Order_ID, Client_ID, Amount_due, Employee_ID, CONVERT(nvarchar, DeliveryDate, 104) AS DeliveryDate, Delivered FROM Orders";
}

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL1, con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable table = new DataTable();
da.Fill(table);
dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingSource(table, null);
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **like** operator, see:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Something like:

```
WHERE Order_ID LIKE '%THE_ID_FRACTION_YOU_HAVE%'
```

THe "%" is a wildcard that allows you to search even if the part you know is not the beggining or the end of the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Using your example, you would do something like this:

```
strSQL1 = strSQL1 + "Order_ID LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
```